# CALL SCREEN (not modal) in modal dialog box not allowed

Tags: abap, dynpro

I have a program who does the following:
The user asks from the program to display the Z* tables in an ALV.
Then it selects a table and press the button SELECTTAB which it will run the following command:

```
  **--Display screen with the fields listed for the given table
  call screen 200 starting at 10 2  ending at 70 22.
```

But the program stops with the following error:
**CALL SCREEN (not modal) in modal dialog box not allowed**

What I want is the following:
1. The user selects a table from the ALV.
2. The program displays a screen with the 1st 100 fields of the table with a checkbox in from. The user selects the desire ones and press OK.
3.  The system display the fields as a selection screen, the user fill with the desire values and press OK.
4. Finally, the program display the records in an ALV and the user proceeds with the final actions.

The error occurs in the 2nd step.
Thanks

Comment: It is very hard to say anything without a [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example).

Comment: Jagger, I have searched in the database and select all tables which start with Z letter and put them in an ITAB. Then I display the results (ITAB) with the FM REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY.

Comment: Jagger, I have searched in the database and select all tables which start with Z letter and put them in an ITAB. Then I display the results (ITAB) with the FM REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY.  Then the user selects a row with the table name and press the button SELECTTAB. The program check the sy-ucomm and if it is equal to SELECTTAB starts to find the 1st 100 fields of the selected table and display to the user with a checkbox in front of the field's name.  What I want to do is to transfer the code from Z_DYMAMIC_SELECTION_SCREEN to my program. So the **CALL SCREEN** is from this program.

Answer (score 2):

You posted the same question in the SAP forum, which has an answer : cf https://answers.sap.com/questions/433450/sap-call-screen-not-modal-in-modal-dialog-box-not.html